# Is it possible to implement point in time recovery (PITR) in PostgreSQL for a single table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a database with lots of tables, but there's one big table that's being updated regularly. At any given point in time, this table contains billions of rows, and let's say that the table is updated so regularly that we can expect a 100% refresh of the table by the end of each quarter. So the volume of data being moved around is in the order tens of billions. Because this table is changing so constantly, I want to implement a PITR, but only for this one table. I have two options:

1. Hack PostgreSQL's in-house PITR to apply only for one table.
2. Build it myself by creating a base backup, set up continuous archiving, and using a python script to execute the log of SQL statements up to a point in time (or use PostgreSQL's EXECUTE statement to loop through the archive). The big con with this is that it won't have the timeline functionality.

My problem is, I don't know if option 1 is even possible, and I don't know if option 2 even makes sense (looping through billions of rows sounds like it defeats the purpose of PITR, which is speed and convenience.) What other options do I have?